# How to draw a contour overlaid on Mapkit view

Tags: uiview, ios4, mapkit, mkannotation

is there a way to draw a shape or contour, overlaid on a map kit view, making sure it's bound to it so when the map kit view moves or re-scales it adjusts accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at the "Location Awareness Programming Guide" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html and specifically at the `MKOverlay` protocol and `MKOverlayView` classes.

These should be exactly what you are looking for.